# bundle install gives Bundler::Dsl::DSLError

Tags: ruby, windows, rubygems, bundler, ubuntu-18.04

bundle install is giving `Bundler::Dsl::DSLError` error

```
 bundle install
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.10/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:120:in `rescue in filesystem_access': Bundler::Dsl::DSLError
        from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.10/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:118:in `filesystem_access'
        from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.10/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/bundler.rb:430:in `read_file'
        from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.10/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/bundler/dsl.rb:46:in `eval_gemfile'
        from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.10/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/bundler/plugin.rb:60:in `gemfile_install'
        from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.10/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/bundler/cli/install.rb:60:in `run'
        from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.10/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/bundler/cli.rb:235:in `block in install'
        from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.10/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/bundler/settings.rb:143:in `temporary'
        from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.10/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/bundler/cli.rb:234:in `install'
        from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.10/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.10/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
        from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.10/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
        from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.10/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/bundler/cli.rb:27:in `dispatch'
        from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.10/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:466:in `start'
        from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.10/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/bundler/cli.rb:18:in `start'
        from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.10/bin/bundle:30:in `block in <main>'
        from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.10/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:124:in `with_friendly_errors'
        from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.10/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
        from /home/kiprosh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.10/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
        from /home/kiprosh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.10/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
```

I am using `Windows 10` machine with `Ubuntu 18.04 LTS app`

Any idea how to fix?

Comment: Not sure which bundler version you are using but there are several causes for filesystem_errors, see https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/9295e5df66bfc989bbc5a1c80e24f2233a8ad292/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb#L102

Answer (score 2):

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 with WSL on windows. Sometimes I open the application directory with an editor on Windows. When doing so, the permissions are changing on the ubuntu side.

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
        21: from /home/omfaer/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
        20: from /home/omfaer/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
        19: from /home/omfaer/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/exe/bundle:34:in `<top (required)>'
        18: from /home/omfaer/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:123:in `with_friendly_errors'
        17: from /home/omfaer/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/exe/bundle:46:in `block in <top (required)>'
        16: from /home/omfaer/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/cli.rb:24:in `start'
        15: from /home/omfaer/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:476:in `start'
        14: from /home/omfaer/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/cli.rb:30:in `dispatch'
        13: from /home/omfaer/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:399:in `dispatch'
        12: from /home/omfaer/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
        11: from /home/omfaer/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        10: from /home/omfaer/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/cli.rb:255:in `install'
         9: from /home/omfaer/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/settings.rb:124:in `temporary'
         8: from /home/omfaer/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/cli.rb:256:in `block in install'
         7: from /home/omfaer/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/cli/install.rb:61:in `run'
         6: from /home/omfaer/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/plugin.rb:76:in `gemfile_install'
         5: from /home/omfaer/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/settings.rb:124:in `temporary'
         4: from /home/omfaer/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/plugin.rb:81:in `block in gemfile_install'
         3: from /home/omfaer/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:46:in `eval_gemfile'
         2: from /home/omfaer/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler.rb:534:in `read_file'
         1: from /home/omfaer/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:102:in `filesystem_access'
/home/omfaer/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:105:in `rescue in filesystem_access': Bundler::Dsl::DSLError
```

The permissions of the Gemfile file have changed.

```sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 omfaer omfaer      691 May 28  2019 .gitignore
---------- 1 omfaer omfaer     1583 Feb 28 11:47 Gemfile
-rw-r--r-- 1 omfaer omfaer      185 May 28  2019 README.md
-rw-r--r-- 1 omfaer omfaer      227 May 28  2019 Rakefile
```

I fixed the permissions and the problem is resolved.

```sh
$ chmod 644 Gemfile
```

I hope this helps you.